# Check if an index exist in the matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

Suppose I have an matrices like below

```
m =
1 3 4 5 7
8 3 6 9 1
9 1 4 2 0
```

Now I want to check if the index m(18) exist which obviously don't in this case. but how can i check it in MATLAB?

Comment: Linearize the matrix and then check whether there is an element at index 18 ?

Comment: MATLAB itself checks if the index is in the valid range if not error message shown

Comment: but i need to check because i want to apply some functions if the values dont exist...

Comment: 18 is the row or the column? Or are you saying in your example m(10) would be 1?

Comment: use if statement : `index = 18; if index > numel(m); disp('ERROR');end`

Comment: @rahnema1 .. thanks.. that will work.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Matlab display error "**index exceeds matrix dimensions**" when you are trying to use larger index and stopping the execution program. Instead of checking indexs exceed or not you should develop a solution to avoid this error.

Generally you can face this error while you are using the loops. You can get use `[m,n] = size(A)`. **Number of row** ***m*** and **number of column *n*** of A matrix. So you can detect your limitation while indexing.

> Maximum index you can use for row **equals to number of row m**.
>
> Maximum index you can use for column **equals to number of column n**.

Comment: The index exceeding may be part of the design.  You shouldn't judge unless you know why they want to do this... so for now, just let the OP do what they want.